# Is the plot of the Mega Evolution specials related to the rest of the Pokémon anime?

Tags: pokemon

I'm very interested in watching the Mega Evolution specials, but I'm afraid the plot is intertwined with the rest of the Pokémon anime, which I haven't been following.

Is the plot of the Mega Evolution specials related to the rest of the anime or do they follow their own plot?

Comment: If I remember correctly, besides some flashbacks, it is a completely standalone story (side story)

Answer (score 2):

The mega evolution series focuses on a character named Alain who is later on introduced into the main anime in the xyz series. The mega evolution series plays a very important part in the plot, hence I would advise watching it in sequence with the Pokemon X and Y and XYZ anime.